# Gridview still displays when navigating away then returning

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, gridview

I am sure this is not a unique problem, but I am drawing a blank (Monday morning) on how to fix it.

On my Nav menu, user opens a page with a DDL, selects a record from drop down which opens up a single line in a Gridview with a few fields displayed. User can click Edit and Update two fields or of course Cancel, or select another record from the drop down which displays the new record in the Gridview.

All this works fine.

Issue is when the user goes to Nav menu and goes to another page then comes back to the first page, the last record that was being viewed is still displayed in the Gridview instead of showing only the DDL and waiting for a selection. Its as if the Page Load event does not fire again (In fact it does not). I need it to fire as an initial load, in order for the 'If Not ISPostback Then' logic to properly fire.

It seems the page is cached and simply reloaded or redisplayed, is there any event that fires or is this all browser??

thanks for any ideas.

Comment: Sounds like you're seeing it again because of view state, without code sample I can only imagine that you need to do something when the user clicks on another nav link (reset the grid view)

Comment: Hi @Nick, sorry there isn't really much code, its so basic. Can you explain to me how to reset the gridview on a nav click?

Comment: It sounds like a browser/cache issue.  Have you set NoCache, etc.?  `Response.Cache.SetCacheability(HttpCacheability.NoCache);`

Answer (score 1):

You should ensure that your pages are not being cached, both by IIS and by the end user's browser.

To ensure that the page isn't cached by IIS or the client's browser, you can add the following directive to the top of the page:

```
<%@ OutputCache location="None" %>
```

You can find more information in [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.outputcachelocation.aspx), but this is the same as setting cacheability in the response except it is declarative, which I personally prefer.

As an alternative, if you don't want any pages cached, you can add the following section to the system.web section of web.config:

```
  <caching>
    <outputCache enableOutputCache="false" enableFragmentCache="false" omitVaryStar="true" />
  </caching>
```

More details on this can also be found in [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms228124.aspx).

Comment: I added <%@ OutputCache location="None" %>  to the page directive and no luck. When I navigate away to another page and return to my original page the gridview is still displayed with the last record that was being viewed when I left the page. Doesn't matter how many other pages I view either at least not up to about 10 random sites.

Comment: But I do like the fact that it stops the browser back button issue. Thanks that solved another issue I was working on.

Comment: @marc11h: Ok, that is actually important information to have because it means that the page should no longer be cached. You can double-check this using fiddler (www.fiddle2.com). If the page is cached, when you navigate back to it, the HTTP status will be 304 (I think). If that is the case, there are some other settings that we could tweak to force the page to expire immediately because some browsers aren't nice about caching. Otherwise, we will know the problem is in the code and can start looking there.